# Reading a mix of strings, ints and doubles from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have a .txt file looking like this:

```
1
Some string
Some other string
3
10,5
20
20
```

I need to read all these values into different type of variables. As far as ints and doubles reading from file seems to be working but then it comes to strings the fun begins.
It seems that strings are read but then I try to output them the whole console just crash.

EDIT:
By "crash" I mean that "Not responding" type of message appears. and the code I use is basically:

```
ifstream file;
file.open ("C:\path\file.txt");
file >> int1;

getline(file, string1);
getline(file, string2);
file >> int2;
file >> double1;
file >> double2;
file >> double3;
// ....

file.close();
```

EDIT 2: Somehow instead of 1 value of int1 is -858993460.

I am getting really confused...

EDIT 3: Now all vales are being set but they are not the values written in file.
First int and first srting are fine but second string is red as a 0 and a doubles are all red as

```
-92559631349317830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Since there are some more values in the file and they accept pattern by type I ran a cycle to get them all the problem is that after first read the values are not red again.

Comment: Information related to that 'just crash'? And what about some code?

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? What is the error message?

Comment: @Povylas Is these types sorted? (i.e. repeating the same manner)

Comment: @Povylas The code snippet you posted doesn't really show the cause of the crashing problem you're getting. Can you show the entirety of the relevant functions? Have you tried running this through the debugger to see where the 'crashing' or 'hanging' happens in your application?

Comment: @Povylas Could your filestream be left in a bad state due to extracting the wrong type into the wrong variable? This is a common catchya which can cause your main parsing loop to just 'hang'.

Comment: Get an Xml, Json or config parsing library. Done.

Comment: Try `if (!file.is_open()) { cout << "File could not be opened" << endl; return 0; }` after `file.open(...)` to see if the file is even opened or not!

Comment: One common problem with windows is that it hides the known extensions, so if you create a txt file and name it `file.txt`, it could be that the real name of the file is `file.txt.txt` and then in your program you can't open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**file.open ("C:\path\file.txt");**

\ is escape character

fix

**file.open ("C:\\path\\file.txt");**

Answer (score 0):

If these types are repeated the same manner, I suggest:

```
ifstream str("MyFile.dat");
int counter = 0;
const int MAX_DATA_CNT = 4;
const int DOUBLE = 1;
const int INT = 2;
....

while (!str)
{
  if (++counter == MAX_DATA_CNT)
      counter = 1;
  switch(counter)
  {
    case DOUBLE: // input double
       break;
    case INT: // input int
        break;
    ....
  }
}
```